# Change DNS TTL with Amazon Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I've searched over the internet for the answer, but I can't find.
I have around 700 hosted zone, and each one have 35 records,
I would like to change the TTL via script or AWS CLI from 300 to 14400 to all records in each domain.
I will be thankful for any assistance.

Comment: You can use AWS SDK for your favorite programming language and update records via their API. If you have done something about it and have a specific question please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one can help you via ruby gem
https://github.com/pcorliss/ruby_route_53

Answer (score 3):

I've come up to the same issue and this was the first answer I found in google.

Unless I misunderstood ruby_route_53 it's pretty much the same thing as using the aws cli, as in I still needed to enumerate all resource records and make the change to each one individually. Saves me from searching the domain zone id but that's it.

I've developed a simple script that allows for change in TTL or IP address to assist in host migration of many domains which I made available at https://github.com/manuel-sousa/aws-utils/blob/master/updateRoute53.py

This script currently assumes user session has credentials configured and will produce the change to all records in that domain.

Example to change all TTL records of one domain do:
`./updateRoute53.py ttl --domain example.org --ttl 14400`

To change multiple domains, for instance in file domains, you can just use shell for it such as:
`for DOMAIN in $(cat domains) ; do ./updateRoute53.py ttl --domain $DOMAIN --ttl 14400 ; done`

Note: I've just done a few test cases and haven't run into any issues but if someone uses it better do a test run first before including in other scripts.

Comment: thank you for your update, if you need help to do it with ruby, let me know, I can help you.